# GMail converts link parameters to wrong format

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I've made a function in java which sends a HTML e-mail with a link to the user.

It works perfectly in all e-mail clients except for GMail.

When clicked, GMail redirects the link via Google and reformats the link parameters like so:


**Orignal Link**

https://www.mylink.com/page.html?id=0&role=admin


To


**Formatted Link**

https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.mylink.com/page.html?id%3D0%26role%3Dadmin


As you can see, the url parameters are in a weird format so I can't get these parameters out of the url with my javascript function.

Is there any way to prevent this?


Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you're seeing is encoded, in Java you can get the unencoded URL with [`URLDecoder.decode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.mylink.com/page.html?id%3D0%26role%3Dadmin";
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8"));
```

This prints:

```
https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.mylink.com/page.html?id=0&role=admin
```

Javascript also has the function to do this, it's called [`decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI).

Comment: Thanks for your time but that's not what I need. AFTER clicking in the url bar of the browser the link changes.

Comment: So I don't need to convert the URL in Java, I need GMail to not convert my URL into this strange thing.

Comment: So in the e-mail, the links looks fine, but after clicking it. It changed to the formatted link.

Comment: @Splekke Javascript also has the function to do this, it's called [`decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI).